# Isomorphism between a polynomial field and $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $$\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2)$$ Show that exists only one isomorphism between $\mathbb{K}$ and a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ and find the subfield.

I tried to find the subfield but i got no results. Can I have just some tips?

Comment: Well, by factoring out $(x^3-2)$, you’re, in effect, making $x$ a cube root of two. Does this help?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Intuitively, in the quotient we get $X=2^{1/3}$. Thus the quotient ring are polynomials in the cube root of $2$. This suggests that the quotient ring is $\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$. Can you make this formal?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that in general is as follow.

1. You can verificate that your polynomial $x^3-2$ is irreducible for Eisenstein's criterion.
2. Take $\alpha$ a only one real root of your polynomial and defined $\varphi:\mathbb{Q}[x]\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$  by $q(x)\mapsto q(\alpha)$ the evaluation homomorphism which is onto.
3. $ker(\varphi)=\{q(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]: q(\alpha)=0\}$, and as $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a PID then you should check that is iqual to ideal generate for $x^3-2$.
4. Finally, you can use the isomorphism theorem to see that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2)\cong \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This doesn't quite prove what is asked: you need to establish uniqueness. So at least you must take $\alpha$ as the real root (after proving there is only one).

Comment: You'r right! It is important that $\alpha$ lie in $\mathbb{R}.$ Thanks a lot! Althought if there exist more of one real root the generated fields are isomorphics, isn't? It's not necesary proving that $\alpha$ is only one.

Comment: The fact that there is just one real root of $X^3-2$ is enough. For if we have an embedding of $K$ in $\mathbb{R}$ then the coset of $X$ goes to some $\alpha_1$ with $\alpha_1^3=2$, so $\alpha_1=\alpha$ and we're done.